# Laravel - renaming table column name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I'm fairly new to the Laravel framework and while still experimenting, I tried

```
->get(array('category AS name', 'url AS page_url'))
```

It feels like cheating doing it this way and if there is a better way or reason why I should not do this, please let me know.

Comment: I don't see any problem in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an accessor:

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $appends = array('name', 'page_url');

    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['category'];
    }

    public function getPageUrlAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['url'];
    }

}
```

with the name you want. You can see the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for more details.